# How to place Svg Circle into middle of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to place a large svg circle into the middle of the page - horizontally and vertically. Not working, any tips?

Here is my code - using jade and scss:

jade:

```
     .logo
        svg.logo__svg
           circle(
              r=300
              style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-width:1;")
```

scss:

```
    .logo{
      height: 80%;
      width: 80%;

      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      @include element('svg'){
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many offsets and transforms.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.logo {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.logo__svg {
  width: 402px;
  height: 402px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">

  <svg class="logo__svg">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="200" style="fill:none;stroke:white;stroke-width:1;"/>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo
  svg.logo__svg(width='100', height='100')
    circle(cx='50%', cy='50%', r='10')
```

try to remove inner-style from logo class